# How to read the content of xml with same multiple nodenames with xpath in php?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

i have a xml string where i have to check for a specific character.
In order to check for it i have to walk through all the node  values.

the xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
     <epos-print xmlns="http://www.epson-pos.com/schemas/2014/05/epos-print"><pulse/>
      <text align="center" ul="0" em="0" dw="1" dh="1" smooth="1" lang="de">Shoppingqueen</text>
      <feed/>
     <text align="center" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="1" lang="de">Text me</text>
     <feed/>
     <text align="center" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="1" lang="de">Hello People</text>
      <feed/>
      <text align="left" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Hello world</text>
     <feed line="2"/>
     <text align="center" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Some text</text>
     <feed line="2"/>
     <text align="left" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Chocolate                         20,00 EUR A</text>
     <feed/>
     <text align="left" ul="1" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Apples                      15,00 EUR A</text>
     <feed/>
     <text align="left" ul="0" em="1" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Onion                   35,00 EUR  </text>
     <feed line="2"/>
     <text align="left" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Cash                     35,00 EUR  </text>
     <cut/>
  </epos-print>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is just one approach i have tried of many:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlText);

$texts = $xml->xpath("epos-print/text");

while(list( , $text) = each($texts)) {
    echo 'b/c: ',$text,"\n";
}
```

I think that xpath is the most easiest it can be used.
I tried it for so many different kind but i get no results.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the elements you are after have a default namespace (in the `epos-print` element you have `xmlns="http://www.epson-pos.com/schemas/2014/05/epos-print"`).

This means that your XPath needs to use this to reference the elements, so first register it with the document (I use 'd' as a prefix to be short) and then prefix your element names with this new namespace...

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlText);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("d", "http://www.epson-pos.com/schemas/2014/05/epos-print");
$texts = $xml->xpath("//d:epos-print/d:text");

foreach ( $texts as $text ) {
    echo 'b/c: ',(string)$text,"\n";
}
```

Also using `//d:epos-print/d:text` with '//' at the start means that the `epos-print` can be located anywhere in the document.